# Shared/exclusive lock mechanism for iPhone & Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, locking

Is there a standard shared/exclusive locking/semaphore scheme for iPhone/Objective-C?  (Something to synchronize operations on internal objects, not file accesses.)

Or, if I have to roll my own, what would be the best primitives to build on?

I need this to implement separate read and write locks, to improve concurrency.  (This should be obvious, but I guess you have to spell out everything.)

Comment: Can you clarify the sort of problem you're trying to solve? Perhaps an example? Strikes me that these sorts of questions of employing techniques from other languages usually translate to just a slightly different design in iOS rather than a reproduction of the other development environment's constructs. For example, to prevent locking on db/object for which you can't support simultaneous access, rather than locking mechanism, you might use a GCD queue. Etc. By the way, GCD does permit semaphores if you need it.

Comment: Objective-C includes the `@synchronized()` directive: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocThreading.html Like Robert Ryan mentions, GCD can be a great way to do multithreading in iOS (and Mac OS X) avoiding some (but not all!) of the tedium and difficulty involved in writing more traditional multithreaded code.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen -- `@synchronized` does not enable shared/exclusive.  And using GCD queues (if it were even possible) would require totally restructuring a large amount of existing iPhone code.

Answer (score 1):

You've several options. implementations are typically based on interfaces in:

```
 #include <pthread.h>   // << for locks and threads
 #include <semaphore.h> // << for semaphore
```

Cocoa (for example) wraps the locking interfaces with `NSLock` (and specializations).

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for something "canned", but if I have to I'll probably use those.  I'm also looking at NSConditionLock, which looks very close to having the necessary primitive features.  It's unfortunate that `@synchronized` doesn't implement a shared/exclusive option.

Comment: @HotLicks well, there are multiple abstractions which use the fundamentals i cited. `@synchronized` is the least efficient (among what's been mentioned so far).

Comment: Actually, I'm seeing that pthread has pthread_rwlock, which would be all I need, if it's efficient and reasonably "fair".  (And if iOS actually implements it.)

Comment: @HotLicks they're very efficient.